# High Charts Graph insert into PDF using FPDF library

Tags: php, highcharts, fpdf

I am converting php script into Pdf using FPDF library.I want to insert High Chart Graph in PDF using FPDF library.Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps if you export the chart as an image using the highcharts exporting module and then embed the image in the PDF using the FPDF->Image() function?

Comment: You mean when  user want to 10 times download pdf then 10 times image export on my server on my server and then embed on pdf?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this with tcpdf. The easiest way to do this is render the [charts on the server](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts) and convert it into an image and ensure that it's saved on the server before importing it in.

Once you've saved the image on the server, [import the image](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto2.htm).